# Sending Correlation ID in AWS SQS

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have implemented sending a message to an SQS queue using the AWS SDK for .NET, is there a way to retrieve the Correlation ID from the message?  I know that .NET System.Messages has a way of doing this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.message.correlationid(v=vs.110).aspx), thought SQS should provide something similar.  Thanks!

Comment: It seems as if you have perhaps not read the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-queue-message-identifiers.html).

Comment: Thanks Michael, I actually have.  However I see we can retrieve the MessageID, would it be the same?  I'm new to SQS :)